# How to prevent the IceFaces "Connection is lost" problem

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I'm using IceFaces 1.8.2 with Tomcat 6

On a irregular basis I get the message "Connection is lost" with the option to reload the page. This is not acceptable for a public site.

My question now is if this approach makes sense:

```
 Ice.onConnectionLost('document:body',
 function() {


             window.location.href=window.location.href;
        });
```

The idea is to reload the current page on connectin problems. Do oyu think this would solve the issue or could this create other problems (I assume that reloading the current url is OK and does not cause any workflow issues).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read here [Icefaces Documentation](http://www.icefaces.org/docs/v1_8_2/htmlguide/devguide/AdvancedTopics6.html#1082322) or any of the 1000+ related posts in the [forums](http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/forums/list.page).

If it's the modal popup that's 'not acceptable', try using the [OutputConnectionStatus Component](http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/connectionstatus-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks, I know the OutputConnectionStatus Component and how to disable the popup.
The problem is, when the connection times out no buttons are clickable anymore, what I'm trying with my Javascript code is the auto-recover the lost connection.

Comment: IIRC, the only way to prevent the modal popup is with the OutConnStat component.  If you put that on your page, your JS could enable a refresh button/link.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all of those

```
Ice.onSessionExpired('document:body', function() {
    location.reload(true);
});
Ice.onServerError('document:body', function() {
    location.reload(true);
});
Ice.onConnectionTrouble('document:body', function() {
    location.reload(true);
});
Ice.onConnectionLost('document:body', function() {
    location.reload(true);
});
```

and use

```
<ice:outputConnectionStatus styleClass="navConnectionStatus" displayHourglassWhenActive="true" showPopupOnDisconnect="false"/>
```

Hope it'll help